# xslt any way to get the name of calling template from within a template

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am very new to XSLT. I was wondering if there is any way to get the name of calling template from within a template.

I currently got the following with a little complex structure. One template is included once directly and once via another template. I need to add a new tag to this template only if it is called from a specific template.

```
<xsl:element name="parent">
     <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$myVariable = 'process1'">
              <xsl:call-template name="templateA"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:call-template name="templateB"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:element>

<xsl:template name="templateA">
    <!-- Some Other Tags Here -->
    <xsl:call-template name="templateB />"
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templateb"> <!-- very big template -->
    <!-- existing tags here  -->
    <!--  Add a new tag here only if called via templateA -->
</xsl:template>
```

To be clear,

As you can see, *templateB* is included either way, but *templateA* adds some more tags then includes *templateB*.

I want to add a new tag to *templateB* only if it is called from *templateA*. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use parameter

```
<xsl:template name="templateB"> <!-- very big template -->
    <xsl:param name="calledFrom" select="" />
    <!-- existing tags here  -->
    <xsl:if test="$calledFrom = 'templateA">
        <!--  Add a new tag here only if called via templateA -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And then called it in this way

```
<xsl:call-template name="templateB">
    <xsl:with-param name="calledFrom" select="'templateA'" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If a function/template needs to know where it was called from, then there's something wrong with the design. Passing a parameter is of course the immediate way to fix the code, but piling on parameters and adding conditional logic based on the parameter values leads to unmaintainable spaghetti.

There's not enough of your code here to assess the design, but I would ask why it's not making more use of template rules rather than named templates. It might well be that judicious use of apply-templates would solve the problem much more naturally.

Comment: Yup. Thanks a lot for your reply. I am dealing with legacy code here :)

Comment: My rule of thumb when dealing with legacy code is to always try and leave it more maintainable than when I found it. Except possibly when there's no spec and no regression tests in which case my rule of thumb is: don't change anything!

Answer (score 1):

Passing the parameter is the solution, I was not aware of if they are passed in nested templates.

The solution that proper suits my scenario is  [`tunnel-params`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params).

Parameters are tunneled(passed on ) to template called by default in xslt 2.0, but in xslt 1.0 we need to specify `tunnel="yes"`. With tunelling `myVariable` can be accessible to the template called.